# How do I plot a graph with specific x-axis range?

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot a curve with specific x-axis range, for example: `y = 2x`, and only the region of `-1.5 <= x <= -0.7` and `0.7 <= x <= 1.5` are of interest.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: try `Plot[ConditionalExpression[ 2 x, -1.5 <= x <= -0.7 || 0.7 <= x <= 1.5], {x, -2, 2}]` to get [this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8rUI.png)

Answer (score 4):

Specify the domain as a region.

```
Plot[2 x, x ∈ ImplicitRegion[-1.5 <= x <= -0.7 || 0.7 <= x <= 1.5, {x}]]
```

[image: plot]